# Autoresize static cell by overweight label

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have some static cells and this don't want to change their size by overweight content in label. I have all constraints(`top`, `bottom`, `leading`,`tralling`) in each cells, also I have this code:

```
import UIKit

class FilmTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var posterView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var directorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var actorsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var plotLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RatingLabel: UILabel!

    private let networkingService = NetworkingService()
    var filmImbdbID = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadFilm(filmImbdbID)


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    }

    private func loadFilm(_ film: String) {

        networkingService.fetchFilmRecording(matching: film) { [weak self] response in

            guard let `self` = self else {
                return
            }

            self.directorLabel.text = response.recordings?.director
            self.titleLabel.text = response.recordings?.title
            self.yearLabel.text = response.recordings?.year
            self.actorsLabel.text = response.recordings?.actors
            self.countryLabel.text = response.recordings?.country
            self.plotLabel.text = response.recordings?.plot
            self.RatingLabel.text = response.recordings?.rating

            if let imageUrl = URL(string: response.recordings!.poster) {
                guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) else { return }
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.posterView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also numberOfLines is 0.

When I see this view, it don't work, however if I slide down it looks like this:

[image]

Please, some idea to fix it? :(

Comment: What doesn't work actually? And what is overweight content?

Comment: Have you tried not using `height`-delegate methods?

Comment: Overweight, I mean. The label.text don't fit in cell. You can see it in picture (Actors).

Also I tried use only properties or only methods, but everything is same.

Comment: Try setting the `numberOfLines` of the `label` to 0.

Comment: Oh, forgot, I'll update it in my question. I've set numberOfLines by atributeInspector before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code, cause is not clear what's happening.

Anyway you should use or:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
```

or delegate methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

not both

Comment: if I am not mistaken, i'v'e tried already, but result is same :( Although it works if I slide down, for example, in the bottom of the image. But not after didLoad method. Probably, is it a problem with a method like, tableView.reloadData()?

Comment: can you update your post with code of dataSource setup?

Comment: So it sounds like you _don't_ want unbounded automatic resizing, so either don't use `.automaticDimension`, or add a maximum height constraint to the labels.

Comment: does label constraint for height is `greaterThanOrEqualTo` ?

Comment: I don't have dataSource and Delegation methods for this tableVC. I've updated my post by adding all code from tableVC.

Comment: I passed filmID from another VC, then get json data and update my labels. It didn't work if I use estimatedRowHeight. And I can't use fix cell size, because "Plot" and "Actors" can be different for each film. Just note: If I use reloadData() in viewDidAppear sometimes it works, but if the app didn't have time for getting json, it's not auto-resizing.

Comment: So, I refactored my code and changed the way of populating cells by Dynamic prototype instead of Static, then it worked. Maybe it doesn't work with Static?

Comment: @MichaelSidoruk add a completion block in your fetching json call and insert there the `reloadData()`

Comment: @Alastar, yes, thank you. I did it with dynamic cells(it's better for me now) and it works. Cool. I'd like to give you a plus, but I can't because of reputation :(. When I get 15 reputation, I'll give you a plus :)